# Whats the model of this experiment

Tags: anova, experiment-design, nested-data, nested-models

$36$ blood samples are collected at random from a blood bank and $6$ samples are sent to $6$ laboratories for studies. The assignment of each sample to each laboratory is random.

A friend of mine told me she had a nested model.

The data is given by the following table, where `x` denotes the laboratory:

```
x   sample  val
A   1   339
A   2   302
A   3   338
A   4   268
A   5   283
A   6   291
B   1   283
B   2   299
B   3   337
B   4   280
B   5   345
B   6   299
C   1   282
C   2   320
C   3   287
C   4   319
C   5   325
C   6   333
D   1   289
D   2   334
D   3   326
D   4   339
D   5   290
D   6   290
E   1   283
E   2   255
E   3   284
E   4   280
E   5   270
E   6   264
F   1   279
F   2   268
F   3   307
F   4   297
F   5   313
F   6   325
```

A nested model would look something like this:

$y_{ijk}=\mu+\tau_{i}+\beta_{j(i)}+\epsilon_{k(ij)}$

with $i$ denoting each lab and $j$ - a blood sample - ?

I'm not sure at all, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: the problem is that with this model we only have 1 replication per combination of variables, $k=1$ , thus we cannot calculate the sums of squares for example. . .

Comment: Hi, this is a hierarchical design with samples nested in labs. Depending on your research question you can use a fixed-effect ANOVA (are there mean difference between these six labs) or a random-effect ANOVA (mixed model). Good luck.

Comment: On the face of it, there are only two possible sources of differences in the results: a laboratory effect (which could be represented as a separate distribution for each laboratory) and a random effect (reflecting variation in the blood bank and the random selection of samples from it).  Represent those in your model.  Even when the lab effect is complex, you won't need triple indexing for just two effects!